# Synfig: "Error: No FFmpeg binary found"

Tags: kubuntu, ffmpeg, synfig-studio

I am a Kubuntu user, and I am having problems when tryng to render my synfig animation. Here is a picture of how my parameters are set:

This is how the parameters are set:

[image]

As soon as I click "Render", I get the following error messages:

```
"Error: No FFmpeg binary found"
"Please install ffmpeg or avconv"
"Target initialization failure"ç
```

I have tried changing from AVI to MP4, and setting ffmpeg as the target. But it didn't work.

I do have FFmpeg in my computer, at least, the Ubuntu Software Center says so.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is your Kubuntu version?